# sailsjs: automatically create composite unique index (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, express, sails.js, waterline

I've the following model in my SailsJS application, I want to add composite unique key on the fields 'room_name' and 'school_id'.

What I currently do is run this command from mongo:

```
 db.room.ensureIndex({'room_name': 1, 'school_id':1}, {unique: true})
```

**Question 1**
Am I doing it right?

**Question 2**
Is it possible to modify my model so it automatically invokes this command without manually modifying the mongodb (from mongo command line)?

This is the model

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {

        room_name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        school_id: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        children_count: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails does not currently (as of v0.10) support multi-key indexes, although it is [on our radar](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/109).  For the time being, the way you are doing it--by specifying the index directly in the Mongo console--is the correct (and only) way.

Comment: any estimation to the release date of v0.10? I read the reference and cannot wait. Is it possible to download beta? and will it be a good idea? Thanks

Comment: You can install the Sails beta with `npm install sails@beta`. We are wrapping up documentation and hope to release soon.

Answer (score 4):

I created a sails hook to give advanced indexing options for models that use the sails-mongo adapter.

Supports all mongo indexing options.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-mongoat

Answer (score 1):

Captain's log, stardate -303842.4081367327 (27th February 2019). Our destination is framework Sails 1.0x.

Even if Sails 1.0x/Waterline supports MongoDB composite indexes declaration in models (I'm not sure about that), when deploying your application in production, the indexes WILL NOT BE CREATED automatically... sad but true :(

Having that in mind...

**Question 1** - Am I doing it right?

Yes you are... indexes are a bit complex and sometimes you will need to change them in production environment, so doing it by hand is necessary sometimes.

**Question 2** - Creating indexes automatically

Yah... doing things by hand that could be done *automagically* is a pain in the *donnuts*...

For this issue, you can use the *config/bootstrap.js* file. Instead of *ensureIndex* function (it has been deprecated), you can use *createIndex* function (ensureIndex was an alias to createIndex). 
A working example of how to AUTOMATICALLY do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359806/sailsjs-best-way-to-create-and-manage-indexes-on-sails-mongo-mongodb/54876328#54876328).

Answer (score 0):

I am using migrations https://github.com/tj/node-migrate

for generating indexes

[my code example](https://gist.github.com/1nstinct/0a60e6e6ad24f92efce3.js)